How to go back to home when refreshing Flutter web app from browser?
I am developing a flutter app with Getx, on Android and IOS is working fine, but if i use it on web, when I refresh from the browser, I lose the navigation stack and I stay "blocked" in the page, because the arrow icon to go back also disappears. I also lose some data that I passed from previous pages. The ideal for me is to go back to the /home after a browser refresh. This is my main
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await GetStorage.init();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  Controller c = Get.put(Controller());
  c.verificaIdDevice();
  c.getimpostazioni();
  
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(
    locale: const Locale('it', 'IT'),
    supportedLocales: const [
      Locale('it', 'IT'),
    ],
    theme: ThemeData(
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243), /* primary: Colors.green */),
      //scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade200
    ),
    localizationsDelegates: GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegates,
    initialRoute: c.apikey.value.isNotEmpty? "/home" : "/screenIniziale",
    getPages: [
      GetPage(name: '/home', page: () => Home()),
      GetPage(name: '/insaddebiti', page: () => InsAddebitiUI()),
      GetPage(name: '/listarisorse', page: () => ListaRisorse2()),
      GetPage(name: '/other', page: () => Other()),
      GetPage(name: '/settings', page: () => SettingsUI()),
      GetPage(name: '/targhe', page: () => LetturaTargaUI()),
      GetPage(name: '/estrattoconto', page: () => Estrattoconto()),
      GetPage(name: '/camera', page: () => ScattaFoto()),
      GetPage(name: '/cassa', page: () => CassaUI()),
      GetPage(name: '/firma', page: () => Firma(), preventDuplicates: true),
      GetPage(name: '/qr', page: () => const QrScanner(), preventDuplicates: true),
      GetPage(name: '/infocamera', page: () => RiepilogoCamera()),
      GetPage(name: '/docScanner', page: () => DocumentScannerView()),
      GetPage(name: '/preventivi', page: () => Preventivi()),
      GetPage(name: '/dettaglioPrev', page: () => Dettagliopreventivo()),
      GetPage(name: '/firmaPrivacy', page: () => FirmaPrivacy()),
      GetPage(name: '/gestionePrezzi', page: () => GestionePrezzi()),
      GetPage(name: '/screenIniziale', page: () => const Screeniniziale()),
    ],
  ));
}

Tried to do
html.window.onBeforeUnload.listen((event) {
    Get.offAllNamed('/home'); 
  });

But it causes errors
